# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException thrown when getObjectById() called

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I have an entity with a Key set as follows:

```
KeyFactory.Builder keyBuilder = new KeyFactory.Builder(MyClass.class.getSimpleName(), "uniqueString");
Key = keyBuilder.getKey();
```

To fetch an entity by key I reconstruct the key in the exact same way and call getObjectById() as follows;

```
App app = pm.getObjectById(MyClass.class, keyBuilder.getKey());
```

Most of the time this works fine but at certain times getObjectById throws this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Does anyone know what causes this? I realise this seems like a very vague problem I've described here but that's really all I know. It's so strange it seems like it may even be a bug with App Engine.

Comment: Any exception has a stack trace; maybe its important ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Could the issue be the same as this [one](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=203), which seems may be a bug in the GAE code?  If it is the same, some users have posted work-arounds to the problem.